# The STM32G0 series microcontroller enters undescribed mode

Tags: stm32, flash-memory

I have been sitting with this question for more than a week, I have already run out of strength, I cannot understand how it works and what I am doing wrong ...

And so, I have an STM32G030F6P6 microcontroller. My program needs to do two things with flash memory, namely:

1. Save 8 bit number. I do it like this:

```
    FLASH->KEYR = 0x45670123;
    FLASH->KEYR = 0xCDEF89AB;
 
    while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
 
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_OPTVERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_FASTERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_MISERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_PGSERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_SIZERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_PGAERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_WRPERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_PROGERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_OPERR;
 
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_PER; //Page erase enable
    FLASH->CR |= (15<<FLASH_CR_PNB_Pos); //Page number selection
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_EOPIE; //End-of-operation interrupt enable
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT; // Start erase operation
 
    while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
 
    if (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_EOP)
    {
        FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_EOP;
    }
 
    FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_PER; //Page erase disabled
    //--------------------------------------------------
    while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
 
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_OPTVERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_FASTERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_MISERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_PGSERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_SIZERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_PGAERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_WRPERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_PROGERR;
    FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_OPERR;
 
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_PG; //Flash memory programming enable
    FLASH->CR |= (15<<FLASH_CR_PNB_Pos); //Page number selection
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_EOPIE; //End-of-operation interrupt enable
 
    *(__IO uint32_t*)0x08007800=(uint32_t)mydata;
    *(__IO uint32_t*)0x08007804=0;
 
    while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
 
    if (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_EOP)
    {
        FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_EOP;
    }
    FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_PG; //Page programming disabled
    FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_EOPIE; //End-of-operation interrupt disabled
 
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_LOCK;
```

2. Set read protection memory. I do it like this:

```
    if ((FLASH->OPTR & FLASH_OPTR_RDP) != 0xBB)
    {
      FLASH->KEYR = 0x45670123;
      FLASH->KEYR = 0xCDEF89AB;
 
      FLASH->OPTKEYR = 0x08192A3B;
      FLASH->OPTKEYR = 0x4C5D6E7F;
 
      while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
 
      FLASH->OPTR |= (0xBB << FLASH_OPTR_RDP_Pos);
 
      while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
      FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_OPTSTRT;
      while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
      FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_LOCK;
    }
```

After, if you restart the power supply, the microcontroller goes into some kind of incomprehensible state and it can no longer be programmed. It generally ceases to be determined by the programmer through the SWD interface. I also see that my program is not running. (I know this because it should flash the LED)

At the same time, I noticed that after I program the microcontroller, but do not turn off the power, I have the opportunity to connect to it and even erase the memory or write a new program to it. But no matter what I do after a power reset, everything leads to one result - the inability to connect to this microcontroller in any way.

I also noticed that after programming with this program, when I am in debug mode, sometimes (I did not find a pattern) the program can go into the address space> 0x1fff0000 and crashes there.

I don’t know what exactly affects the microcontroller writing to memory or setting read protection. But if I remove these two functions from the program, everything works without problems.

Thus, I have already "spoiled" more than 10 microcontrollers, and in order to continue to deal with this problem, I do not want to "sacrifice" new ones.

I use the original ST LINK V2 programmer and original STM32G030F6P6 microcontrollers, as well as the latest versions of STM32CubeIDE 1.11.2, STM32CubeProgrammer v2.12.0 and STM32 ST-LINK Utility.

The programmer is connected according to this scheme

If I forgot to mention something, I am ready to answer any questions. If you need to provide any diagrams, code snippets or any other information, just ask.

I welcome any idea, any opportunity to get to the bottom of the truth! If you need to "kill" more controllers - I'm ready!

If anyone has any ideas how to bring broken microcontrollers back to life (any idea) I'm willing to try.

Note from 17/02/2023:

Thanks to everyone who is trying to help. Sorry for not answering right away, I needed time and this is what I came up with:

1. Now I have one microcontroller connected to debugging with which I can test, so if you have any ideas, write!
2. If you run any program (without any interruptions - this is important), then everything works fine, the program is executed, debugging works, it stops at breakpoints. When debugging is disabled, everything continues to work.
3. If you configure at least one any interrupt (I tried it from ADC, DMA, TIM), then something unknown happens. As soon as an interrupt should occur, the program jumps to >0x1fff0000 and stays there forever. Next, I spent a lot of time reading about how interrupts work. As I understood from the documentation:

There is a table of interrupt vectors. RM0454 Rev 5 page 250/989
[image]

When and how it is written, I did not quite understand, but as I understand it, it is written to the address that lies in the VTOR register
[image]

In the end, I put a breakpoint before starting the interrupt and looked at this register
[image]

I saw 0 there, which seemed strange to me ... It turns out that the addresses of the interrupt vectors are from address 0?

Next, I unpaused the program so that an interrupt occurred and also hung on the address space> 0x1fff0000, but if you pause in the VTOR register, it will already be just 0x1fff0000. Coincidence? Don't think. I also noticed that in FLASH the Latency register was set to 2. I don’t know what this is connected with, but it’s a fact.
[image]

4. I realized that all this goes away not when I set the read protection, but when I write to the last page of the flash memory. What can happen that the controller goes into such a state?
5. I deliberately do not turn off the power of this MK now, because I believe that after that it will also cease to be detected by the SWD interface.
6. Maybe I forgot to mention something, so ask.
7. Also, if you remove the FLASH entry from the program, then it works absolutely fine on another same microcontroller. That is, it's all about writing to memory. To be honest, it doesn’t fit in my head what can be done when writing to memory in order to spoil the microcontroller in such a way ... I thought you could get only two states, either everything works or it doesn’t work. And here it turns out that everything seems to be working, until the interrupt is triggered. And again, even the complete erasure of flash memory does not bring the microcontroller out of this state. I don't understand. After all, I could not change other parts of the memory, except for flash, or could I?

Comment: You are overusing the `|=` operator. Especialy with SR register. To clear all the error bits just write `FLASH->SR = FLASH_SR_OPTVERR;` etc. The SR registger contais some _rs_ bits. Where _rs_ means "Software can read as well as set this bit. Writing 0 has no effect on the bit value." In other cases you can set some bits without clearing old ones, like with writing `PNB`. To avoid bricking more controllers, ensure first, that writing and clearing flash works as expected.

Comment: Flash protection needs a power reset.

Comment: Is this a custom board or one of STM32's sample boards (e.g. Nucleo)? Do you have BOOT0 pulled up or down (or neither)?

Comment: @pmacfarlane This board is my design. This microcontroller has 3 boot bits, namely BOOT0, BOOT1 and BOOT_SEL. They all default to 1, so I can't control the outside pin of BOOT. If I put BOOT_SEL=0, then I can control the external pin.

Comment: The VTOR always starts off with the value zero.  On STM32 address zero is an alias for address 0x08000000, so it is reading the addresses of your interrupt functions from the few words above there.  0x1FFF0000 is the ROM bootloader.  Read AN2606 to find out about that.  Flash latency must be set depending on the speed of your processor.  Eg: 2 means you are running above 60MHz, your project should include code that sets this.  You should edit the question to include your vector table definition and your startup routine.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `|=` is very awkward.  You cannot access individual fields of a register separately, so I suggest you learn not to try.  Every time you write to a register you are writing *something* to the other bits.  Even writing zeros or the same bits back again that you read might not be safe.

If you have bricked a board then there is almost certainly something wrong with your use of the option bytes.  Take out all the code about writing normal flash until you can set and clear those bits reliably.

I suspect that maybe the problem here is that you are only checking the busy bit of flash bank 1.  Unless you are trying to do things with both banks in parallel it will be harmless to always poll until all three busy bits in in the status register are zero at once.

Also you should poll for the OPTLOCK bit in the FLASH_CR to go to zero after writing FLASH_OPTKEYR before doing anything else.

Comment: *`Even writing zeros or the same bits back again that you read might not be safe.`* nonsense

Comment: Writing an implicit zeros to a field of type rc_w0 will clear a flag that you didn't mean to. Even |= BB above is risky because the zeros in the BB will not be cleared they will just be written back with the value that was there previously.  Suppose the value previously was x44 for protection level 1.  doing |= 0xBB will result in 0xCC and set protection level 2 and brick the board from future programming.

Comment: @Tom V
Yes, I will consider it.
You can read my “Note from 17/02/2023:”
This microcontroller contains only 1 bank, so I thought that it makes no sense to check bank 2 ...

Comment: @Tom V
Yes I understood this error about |=. In this case, by default, 0xAA is written in the RDP register, so writing 0xBB there will give me 0xBB

Answer (score 0):

1. You are writing to a low flash address and you are not using any linker defined memory region/section. You don't even erase the block before writing, that can cause problems (maybe you are writing over your program).
2. After protecting with rdp, you cannot read/write ram/flash by debugger, you can only work on option bytes. Use stm32cubeprogrammer to remove rdp.
3. Depending on the device, your micro can enter bootloader if the first word of the flash is empty. Maybe this can describe your mcu executing at 0x1fffxxxx. Or maybe you have a floating boot pin.
4. Option bytes are reloaded when you powercycle or with a specific write. So it's normal you see your protection working only after a power cycle.
5. From the device errata:

> 2.2.3 Under Level 1 read protection, booting from Main Flash memory selected through PA14‑BOOT0
> pin is not functional
> Description
> With the Flash memory read protection set to Level 1 and the boot mode selected through the PA14-BOOT0 pin
> (BOOT0 function of the pin), an attempt to boot from Main Flash memory can wrongly be interpreted by the read
> protection mechanism as an unauthorized access, preventing the user code execution. Booting from Main Flash
> memory operates correctly if selected through option bits (nBOOT_SEL and nBOOT0 both set).

Comment: 1. I write in the last block of memory. Before that, I repeatedly checked that it was empty.
Please read my "Note dated 17/02/2023" for more information.

Comment: Just for a note: empty check is not enough, that flash has 72bit row with 8bit correction code, you cannot rewrite it even if you write all user bits to 1 0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF. That is also what something objcopy does is you tell him to fill the gaps in memory.

Comment: And in my opionion, for the problem you describe, you're are messing with the option bytes. That could force program in bootloader and make you difficult to erase the chip (if you inadvertently enable sector protection or bank protection. Sometimes is quite hard to recover them because you have to unlock some option in order and make it update between steps by powercycling it. Sagger has a nice tool to unlock them that works most of the times. You can reprogram freely your st-link to j-link (there a sagger official tool for st boards) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your help. At the cost of another microcontroller, I finally figured out what was going on! I was wrong when I thought it was because of writing to flash. As a result, what I have now:
We do all the points below without turning off the power.

1. We program with any program.
2. We put L1 protection through proprietary utilities. (STM32 ST-LINK Utility or STM32CubeProgrammer, it doesn't matter, the effect is the same), while the program stops executing for some reason.
3. We remove L1 protection through proprietary utilities. The memory is accordingly erased. (STM32 ST-LINK Utility or STM32CubeProgrammer, it doesn't matter, the effect is the same)
4. After that, if you program with any program where there are interruptions, then after any interruption we go to the area> 0x1fff0000 and hang there endlessly.
   If you program the program without interruptions, everything works properly.
   Next, there are two scenarios:

- If after that you turn off and turn on the power of the microcontroller and at the same time the program is flashed without interruptions, then all work is restored and now you can flash with any program, even with interruptions, even without them. Everything is working normally.
- If after that turn off and turn on the power supply of the microcontroller, but leave the program where the interrupts were, we get a corpse that is not detected by SWD, not by UART.

Note 1: If you program with interrupts and put L1 on and then turn the power off and on, then everything will work fine with L1 protection.
It follows from this that the microcontroller can be transferred to such a state only if you put L1, then remove it, and then, without turning off and on the power, program it with interrupts, which will lead to the microcontroller going to the memory area> 1FFF0000. Then we turn the power off and on and see that at startup (after about 100ms) an interrupt comes (it happened in my program) and then the program goes to the > 1FFF0000 area, from where, as I understand it, SWD is no longer available. But at the same time, in the area> 1FFF0000, the microcontroller somehow freezes, since even the bootloader does not work.

Note 2: Tested with a clean program and a simple blinking LED
Here is the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mtBmZHD-A3YecBccCb6P2EF2i0ArUBNG/view

- programmed, blinking works
- set L1
- removed L1 (memory erased)
- programmed the same program, by interrupt I go to 0x1fff0000
- in this state, turn off and turn on the power and after that the microcontroller is dead
  Used STM32CubeIDE 1.11.2, STM32 ST-LINK Utility and ST link V2 programmer. PC win7 x64. I used ST-LINK Utility because I can't get STM32CubeProgrammer to work on Win7. Connecting the programmer according to the scheme: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101761/1-0/Debug-and-trace-interface/Typical-SWD-circuit. If I forgot to mention something, - just ask.

Comment: What you are still missing is that 0x1fff0000 is the start address of the bootloader where the vector table for the bootloader is and is aliased with address 0 of the flash.
You cannot connect to the "bricked" chips either because you have a problem with you swd connection or because you are messing option bytes and putting the micro in RDP Level 2.